# Web scraping in Java/Scala

Tags: scala, web-scraping, nutch, spray, vert.x

I need to extract keywords, title and description of a long list of URLs (initially ~250,000 URLs per day and eventually ~15,000,000 URLs per day)

How would you recommend executing this? Preferably and solution that could be extended to 15,000,000 events per day. Preferably in Scala or Java

So far I've looked at:

- Spray - I'm not very familiar with Spray yet so I can't quite evaluate it. Is it a useful framework for my task?
- Vertx - I've worked with Vertx before, if this is a good framework could you explain how would to be the best way to implement it with Vertx?
- Scala scraper - Not familiar with it at all. Is it a good framework for the use case and the loads I need?
- Nutch - I'm not sure how good it will be if I want to use it inside my code. Also I'm not sure I need Solr for my usecase. Anyone had any experience with it?

I'll be happy to hear of other options if you think they're better

I know I can probably dig in each of these solution and decide whether it's good or not but there seem to be so many options so any direction will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did something like this using Play Framework (`play-ws` offers a fairly easy-to-use HTTP client) and `jsoup`. It wasn't that bad.

*play-ws: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS
*jsoup: http://jsoup.org/

Comment: How many URLs did you manage to handle per day?

Comment: Oh way way less than you need to.

Comment: The number of URLs per day you can process depends essentially on the diversity of hosts / domains and your politeness settings, e.g. if you have 1M URLs from the same host and have a delay of 1 sec per request then the best you'll be able to do is 86400 pages per day. Anyway, you'll need a distributed crawler like Nutch or StormCrawler.

Comment: is your crawl limited to your seeds URLs or will you be expanding the crawl frontiers? What do you want to do with the info you extract? put them in a DB, in a search engine like SOLR or ES?

Comment: Everyday I will encounter new URLs (old URLs will be cached so no need to scrape them again). After extracting the data I need to perform some NLPs algorithms on the words (TF-IDF, N-Grams etc) and then save the results in some DB, I don't think Solr or ES will help me here (correct me if I'm wrong). Do you have any recommendation between Nutch and StormCrawler?

Comment: @gideon see answer below

Comment: I wrote simple wrapper around apache http-client-async. Spray's capabilities didn't suite me in terms of support for redirects, proxies and etc.

Comment: expert - how many requests could you handle?

Answer (score 3):

We use [StormCrawler](http://www.stormcrawler.net) for our search engine, [StolenCameraFinder](http://www.stolencamerafinder.com). It's all in java and I've clocked it fetching over 4 million urls per day with a politeness setting of 1 url per second *per host*. The bottleneck wasn't StormCrawler but my url diversity. The *per host* part is important, it will never fetch more than 1 url per second for each host (technically it actually leaves a 1 second rest between fetches). For example, if you had 60 URLs for yahoo.com/* and 100 million for flickr.com/* then you will still never exceed 120/min.

You can index the data straight into [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) and that works very well. StormCrawler has hooks right into so you should be able to get something running quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Apache Nutch to crawl around 600k urls in 3 hours. I did use nutch in a Hadoop cluster. However, a friend of mine has used his own in house crawler to crawl 1 millions records in 1 hour.

Ideally, with this scale of your records, you will need a distributed solution. As a result, I recommend using nutch as it suits your need. You could also try Storm crawler. It is similar to Nutch but uses storm as its distribution engine.You might think building a new one is a better option, but I do not think so. Nutch is indeed a matured and scalable solution.

Do you need Solr? it all depends in what you want to do with the end result. If you want to search it, then you will need Solr or Elasticsearch. If you want to crawl and push data into a database then you need to build a new indexer that pushes crawled data to your desired data sink. Which is possible in Nutch.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Storm Crawler does not use Spark - as its name indicated it is based on Apache Storm. Probably explains why you think it is similar to Nutch, they are comparable yet different.

Comment: Thanks Julien for the correction.apparently,  we just lost track of project names.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @ameertawfik you could write a custom indexer class in Nutch so that it sends whichever data you need to keep into a DB. Whether you could use SOLR or ES as indexing backends depends on how you need to use the data.

You could do the NLP processing as part of the Nutch parsing or indexing steps by implementing custom HTMLParseFilters or IndexingFilters. Either way would work fine and since it would be running on Hadoop, the NLP part would also scale.

Nutch would work fine but is probably an overkill for what you need to do. If you know that the URLs you want to fetch are new then I'd just go for StormCrawler instead. Your crawls are non-recursive so it could be a matter of having N queues with RabbitMQ (or any other distributed queue) and inject your URLs daily into the queues based e.g. on their hostname. The SC topology would then require a custom Spout to connect to RabbitMQ (there are examples on the web you can use as starting points), most of the other components would be the standard ones, except a couple of bolts for doing the NLP work + another one to send the results to the storage of your choice.

Either Nutch or SC would be good ways of doing it. SC would certainly be faster and probably easier to understand. I wrote [a tutorial](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/index-web-with-aws-cloudsearch.html) a few months ago which describes and compares Nutch and SC, this might be useful for understanding how they differ.

Comment: Thanks Julien, why do you think Nutch is an overkill? is the initial pressure of 250K requests per day doesn't sound much for Nutch? Also regarding StormCrawler - I couldn't find any tutorials/code examples besides what you gave, how did you find the information for it? Also, how stable is StormCrawler (I can see its September 2015?)

Comment: Nutch can do a lot more than what is required by your usecase. Again the number of request is irrelevant - it's the diversity of URLs and politeness settings that matter. Re-SC I am its author. See [https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki] for additional resources, the website will be updated shortly. There have been releases since Sept and it is used in production by several companies.

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed a headless browser with support for proxies and javascript, I opted to build my own framework based on HtmlUnit and parallelizing it: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-webproxy